# Remote screen is tiny when running x2goclient on a high DPI laptop

Tags: highdpi, x2go

I am using x2go to access a remote xfce4 session from a laptop, also running xfce4. The remote server and the local laptop have x2go installed. The local laptop has a highDPI screen.

I could not find any way to make the remote display show properly, this is always shown with tiny fonts on my local laptop. Apparently the pixels are mapped one-to-one from the remote session to the local session, but the remote session has 73 DPI and the local laptop has aboutr 300 dpi.

Changing the DPI setting in the second config screen for that session does not have any impact at all (at least not when resuming a running session).

I do not want to change anything about the DPI on the remote server since I need to access that remote session from different devices, and only some of them have highDPI. So what I need is a LOCAL way to increase the remote session view, something like pixel doubling.

Setting QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=2 before running x2goclient does not help either with increasing the remote session view.